# SQL query with Northwind database

Tags: sql-server

I have a little problem with some query. 
This is the task:

> Create a query that displays the employees with no sale in the last 3 months to customers who are from "USA".

This is what i wrote:

```
    Select emp.EmployeeID, (emp.FirstName + ' ' + emp.LastName) AS Name
From Employees AS emp
    Join Orders AS o ON emp.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
    Join Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
Where c.Country LIKE 'USA';
```

One of the problem is that i don't know where to put this select query (it's for calculating the last 3 months but i'm not sure that this is true):

> Select DATEDIFF(MM, '1998-02-01', '1998-05-31') From Orders

The second problem is that i don't have an idea for the part ***"employees with no sale"*** How can i find this?

Should i use other kind of joins or something else?

Sorry for my question but i'm new in SQL and i'll appreciate any kind of help.

If you have any questions, please ask. :)

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with northwind database despite of it being highly popular among newbies. Post your tables schema and foreign keys.

Comment: You'll need to find all employees that are NOT in the Orders table.  So, INNER JOINS are not what you need.  Check the Date Function to get 3 months prior to GETDATE()

Comment: Here is the relationship between all tables - [link](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting help from your teacher or one of your classmates on this?

Comment: This is for homework so i can't ask my teacher. I ask some of my classmates but they can't help me too. So i decided to ask for help here :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a query that displays the employees with no sale in the last 3 months to customers who are from "USA"

```
Select * From Employees e
Where not exists
  (Select * from orders o join customers c 
      on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
   Where c.Country = "USA"
      and o.saleDate >= DateAdd(month, -3, getdate()))
```

Comment: I liked the dangling and :P

Answer (score 1):

How you actually treat "last 3 months" depends on you, but this is one way to approach the task:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where not exists (
  select 1
  from orders o
  join customers c on c.customerid = o.customerid
  where e.employeeid = o.employeeid
    and c.country = 'USA'
    and c.orderdate > dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 3)
  );
```

Last three months could mean months per se or just days that make exactly last three months (eg. 91)

Comment: I think that means the last three monts in table "Orders" in this database, but i'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Sisi I'm not asking for the interpretation, I'm just pointing out that the logic might be different and I don't mean records in a table but logic for calculating days - you can change that.

Comment: Thanks anyway :). I hope to rewrite it using the dates in the database.

Comment: @Sisi this should be a working solution with my understanding of "last three months" . . .

Answer (score 1):

If you're just learning SQL, please don't take one of these answers and use it to do your homework.  You'll need to figure out what's going on for yourself.

Try to take this task in pieces.  First, let's look at 'customers from USA.'  You can probably write this one yourself:

```
Select * from customers where country = 'usa'
```

Next, consider how to find the orders for those customers (all of them, for now).

Since you've posted an example of an inner join, I'm going to assume you could write that one yourself, too:

```
Select o.* from customers c inner join orders o on
c.customerID = o.customerID
where country = 'usa'
```

Now you've asked where/how to apply the criteria for 'sales in the last 3 months.'  Note each order has an `orderDate`, representing the date the order was placed.  You need to use the `order` table's `orderdate` field with today's date and compare the number of months between them.  The `getdate()` function returns the date and time from the server.  Try executing:

```
select getdate()
```

then you can experiment with the `datediff()` function on the `orderDate`s in the `orders` table:

```
Select orderid, getdate(), orderdate, datediff(mm,orderdate,getdate())
from orders
```

I think you'll have better luck, though, adding 3 months to `orderdate` and comparing with `getdate()`:

```
Select orderid, orderdate, dateadd(month, orderdate, 3), 
getdate(), dateadd(month, getdate(), -3)
    from orders
```

Now you can see all the employee IDs you **don't** want, the ones that have orders within the last 3 months, and you already know how to limit orders by customers in USA.  Those are the IDs you want to exclude from the `employees` table.  You can do that in a couple of different ways, depending on what you've learned so far, but typically you're exposed to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s for this sort of thing.  You'll want to `left outer join` your `employee` table with the set of IDs you **don't** want (the ones with orders in the past 3 months) on the employeeID field, and return rows where the employeeID from the `order` subquery is null.

Try:

```
select count(*) from employees  -- note rowcount
```

then:

```
select min(employeeID) from orders  -- pick one employee
```

then:

```
select count(e.employeeID) 
from employees e left outer join 
  (select * from orders
   where employeeID in (select min(employeeID) from orders) 
  ) o on e.employeeID = o.employeeID 
where o.employeeID is null
```

this count should be one less than the total number of rows in your `employees` table, it should exclude the lowest employeeID with an order.

Then see if you can figure out how to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Left/Right joins exist as well and you can somewhat think of them as Venn diagrams (Join or Inner Join is the intersect, Left Join is intersect and left circle, etc.). Its one perspective on how to think what will be returned. Fields returned which are not in the intersect like with a Left Join will be NULL.

The below is another way to do it:

```
Select emp.EmployeeID, (emp.FirstName + ' ' + emp.LastName) AS Name
From Employees AS emp
    Left Join Orders As o ON emp.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
        And o.OrderDate > DateAdd(month,-3,GetDate())
    Join Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
Where c.Country = 'USA' And o.EmployeeID is Null
Group By emp.EmployeeID, emp.FirstName, emp.LastName;
```

Comment: This query didn't find any results. I can't understand whether it is because the code or the query is fine and really in the tables it doesn't have results like this.